# tsibble::fill_gaps and reference to numeric column name in variable

Tags: r, tsibble

Here is my code:

```
library(fpp3)
library(dplyr)
my_df <- data.frame("dates" = as.Date(c("2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-05")), 
                    "col_1" = c(1,2,23))
colnames(my_df) <- c("dates", "1")

i <- 1

test <- my_df %>% as_tsibble(., index=dates) %>% 
  fill_gaps(., as.character(i) = 1)
```

it generates error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"test <- my_df %>% as_tsibble(., index=dates) %>% 
  fill_gaps(., as.character(i) ="
```

I also tried

```
test <- my_df %>% as_tsibble(., index=dates) %>% 
  fill_gaps(., !!as.character(i) = 1)

test <- my_df %>% as_tsibble(., index=dates) %>% 
  fill_gaps(., !!quo_name(i) = 1)
```

but got the same error. Is there easy fix? I need to make it work as stated, I cannot change dataframe column names to something non-numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `setNames`

```
my_df %>%
      as_tsibble(., index=dates) %>% 
      fill_gaps(!!! setNames(1, i))
# A tsibble: 5 x 2 [1D]
#  dates        `1`
#  <date>     <dbl>
#1 2020-03-01     1
#2 2020-03-02     2
#3 2020-03-03     1
#4 2020-03-04     1
#5 2020-03-05    23
```

Comment: Thank you! First solution returns: `Error: The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol` the second solution returns: `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `setNames(i, 1)` doesn't exist.`

Comment: @user1700890  second solution would be the reverse for `setNames`

Comment: I do not think I understand your last comment. Overall `fill_gaps` take column name and set gaps in index to something in this case to 1. I need to make `fill_gaps` understand that `i` refers to column named 1. Sorry that replacement value and column name coinside, it adds to confusion.

Comment: I meant `setNames(1, i)` instead of `setNames(i, 1)` earlier in my code

Comment: Still the same error `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `setNames(1, i)` doesn't exist.`

Comment: @user1700890 can you try now

Comment: It worked!!!, How did you obtain such indepth knowledge of R?

Comment: @user1700890 it is just practise.  If I do things on a different platform, I wouldn't be able to perform

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, column names shoud not be numeric, but here you can use backticks if it's necessary:

```
test <- my_df %>% as_tsibble(., index=dates) %>% 
    fill_gaps(., `1` = 1)
```

(You even don't need to define `i`.)

The result is:

```
# A tsibble: 5 x 2 [1D]
  dates        `1`
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2020-03-01     1
2 2020-03-02     2
3 2020-03-03     1
4 2020-03-04     1
5 2020-03-05    23
```

Comment: Thank you, but column name is numeric and it is stored in the variable.